Why is stepwise selection of variable still taught in university statistics classes?
I have on more than one occasion come across both recently-published textbooks and classes that teach the use of stepwise methods for model construction. Why is this still done, given the problems that come along with this method?

Welcome to CV.  We have a large repository of answers to all kinds of statistics-related questions--and you can find plenty of answers to your question by searching our site for stepwise regression.

I think it's a legitimate question. If somebody can find a duplicate that'd be a reason to close it, but "opinion based"??  It is fact that it is taught in many places, and chances are the people who do it have their reasons. These reasons can be of interest regardless of whether one has the opinion that these are good reasons or not.

Voted to reopen. Most of our threads are about why stepwise is bad (and it is), but Bryan is asking why it is still taught in spite of it being bad. Two different things. (If anyone has a duplicate for "why is it taught?", please do post it here.)

@Stephan I voted to reclose (reluctantly overriding three votes to reopen) because "why is this taught" is not the kind of question we can deal with appropriately here.  It's guaranteed to generate controversy, has no definite answer, and invites speculation.

@whuber: that is a closure reason that makes much more sense, and probably send a much more useful signal to the OP. Thank you!

While I agree with the comments above, I think that rewriting the question and clearly asking for references addressing why it is still taught would not elicit opinion-based answers. I think that such references (assuming they exist) are probably more in the scope of sociology or education (or perhaps history) than purely statistics, but I don't think it would make the question off-topic (we do have tags related to more "social" aspects of statistics, e.g. [tag:history], [tag:careers], [tag:ethics], [tag:teaching], etc.).

Much of statistics (at least as taught in the social sciences) is passed down by tradition, which is to say that heuristics are easy, whereas critical thinking about these topics isn't.
There are many garbage ideas that get passed down by non-methodologists purely because that is what the last professor before them regurgitated. The idea that normality "turns on" after $n > 30$ observations. That the $p$-value is the probability of the alternative hypothesis $H_A$ being true. And similarly, how stepwise regression is a useful and seemingly innocuous use of data, which by many accounts is not the case. All of these come from not critically thinking about the issue, but nevertheless sharing it to future generations.
Specific to stepwise regression, I believe that while discussions of stepwise regression problems have been ongoing for many years, that discussion simply hasn't taken place in my field. While I rarely see it employed there, I also have never seen it discredited in my field either. So this can also simply be a cultural thing among research domains, similar to how methods like time series analysis are common in economics but rare in psychology.

I remember reading first about FS and BE algorithms in Seber, Lee, a rather theoretical book than an applied one and comparatively  bit old. The authors did discuss about the drawbacks as reported back in Thompson [1978]. The authors further compared that with APR algorithms and again briefly discussed the possible drawbacks of stepwise methods. Nothing revelatory. Not sure of what is happening in any other study material, especially at the applied front.

You made me realize that I should have emphasized "as taught in the social sciences", which I distinguish now in my answer. I realize that books within statistics itself have covered this in much better detail than the sciences, particularly social science disciplines.

When I saw the question my initial reaction was "Inertia. Ignorance." and your answer is lengthier and loosely has the same tone. That said, I think this is a little harsh. Many, perhaps most, statistical methods have major limitations. Plain or vanilla regression is still taught because it is hard (impossible?) to come up with a simple procedure with more advantages and none of the limitations. Also, selection of predictors is a hard problem. I don't think it's true of stepwise,, but often it's prudent to stick to something older with known limitations rather than to adopt the latest novelty.

I think that is a fair point, but the distinction I make with vanilla regression is that it usually can have some utility and can be laid as a nice bedrock for most of the other regression procedures you learn later. Stepwise regression alternatively seems like a tripwire bomb on the path to learning the rest of statistics, which doesn't in itself serve a great purpose, and doesn't greatly connect to anything else other than perhaps a conversation on more principled regularization techniques. I think if stepwise is taught purely for history, it isn't a bad thing.

@NickCox: all fair points... except for the part about "known limitations", because in my opinion, the limitations of stepwise are absolutely not known by practitioners in social sciences - which is ironic, because many of those disciplines are precisely the ones that most religiously adhere to the Cult Of The Small P Value, so one might naively believe that they might be quite interested in the fact that this common procedure invalidates the entire theory...

@Stephan Kolassa  We agree. Known by experienced people is my intended meaning and specifically I am not recommending stepwise, but making a broader comment. But in the limit every method has some limitations and it's a career-long task to learn about even the most important.
